# consistent times of input variables for model input

Tags: matlab, average

I'm writing some components of a model for predicting water temperature and I have a set of input files (i) air temperature; (ii) radiation; (iii) cloud cover; (iv) wind speed; and (v) relative humidity. In order to pass this data through the equations I first need to ensure that all of the variables are measured at consistent times, where some of the input data can be measured at a resolution of 30 min, 60 min, daily etc and can also have missing data points. Consider these example values:

```
JdayCC = datenum('2011-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DatCC = rand(1,length(JdayCC));

JdayAirT = datenum('2011-04-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):30/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
JdayAirT(200:250) = [];
JdayAirT(400:420) = [];
DatAirT = rand(1,length(JdayAirT));

JdayRH = datenum('2011-02-06 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):3600/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 22:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DatRH = rand(1,length(JdayRH));

JdayWnd = datenum('2011-02-06 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 20:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
JdayAirT(400:420) = [];
DatWnd = rand(1,length(JdayWnd));

JdaySW = datenum('2011-02-07 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 22:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DatSW = rand(1,length(JdaySW));
```

I would like to write a function that would look at all of these variables and would determine the resolution that all of the variables could be averaged to. For example, if the data were

(i) hourly; (ii) hourly; (iii) daily; (iv) 30 min; and (v) daily

then the function would average all of the variables to daily values and would then find the consistent times between all of the variables, and keep these to pass through the equations.

Answer (score 0):

[`diff`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) will tell you the (time) increment between each value of your data `DatCC`, `DatAirT`, etc... to help you determine what the sampling time is (assuming it is uniform sampling). You can then create a timeseries with each data and use [`resample`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.resample.html) to get all your data with the same sample time, the smallest value of your existing sample times.